# Make something visible on right side after an input is entered from a user

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

[image]

Now a user would enter there zip code on the left side. Once entered I want Shipping Method to be visible on the right side. If no zip code is entered then Shipping Method should stay invisible.

[image]
 
First time user with html, css, and c# so any information would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You would have to use javascript for this type of stuff. Css alone wouldn't be able to do it.

Comment: Alrighty, well I updated my question to include javascript now. I am familiar with javascript so any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I stand corrected, see @scott-kaye answer below

Comment: Also, for future reference, your tags should not go in the title bar.

Comment: I edited the question and removed the tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking with the requirement of only HTML/CSS, you can use the `+` immediate sibling selector to conditionally show/hide elements depending on the input's validity.

```css
input:invalid + select { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="\d{5}" placeholder="ZIP code" required>
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I will use this. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcellaRuiz No prob!  I updated it to use the `+` selector instead, which will only show the dropdown if the invalid `input` element is immediately before it.  Previously I was using the `~` selector, which would have shown/hidden *all* dropdowns if any previous input was invalid.